# Divs in same line only on a wider window

Tags: css, css-float

See: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbSjg/)

When the window is long enough, both divs are in the same line, but when it's smaller, the second div(.footers) moves to a new line. I wan't them to be in the same line all the time.

Css from the left div:

```
.footer .footer_links {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 25px 0px 0px 20px;
    min-height: 95px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Css from the right div:

```
.footer .footers {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: you need to specify the width for both div!

Comment: yep i agree with tonsolfx if you define width your content will be the same and in smaller browser you will have horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to give the left div (`.footer_links`) a fixed height, instead of floating the div on the right (`.footers`), give it `overflow:hidden`. This will cause it to fill the remaining width of the page:

```
.footer .footers {
    text-align: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbSjg/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this give `max-width:`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MbSjg/4/)**

**CSS**

```
footer {
    background: #f2f2f2 !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.footer .footer_links {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 25px 0px 0px 20px;
    min-height: 95px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    text-align: left;
}
.footer a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #898989 !important;
}
.footer .footers {
    text-align: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.footer .footers p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #898989;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

in `DEMO2` you have write `max-width:` then its working

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/MbSjg/5/)**

**CSS**

```
.footer .footers {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer .footer_links {
    float: left;
    width: 20%; // In percent
    padding: 25px 0px 0px 20px;
    min-height: 95px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer .footers {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width:70%; // In percent
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to a .footers div a white-space , and fixed height:

```
.footer .footers {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    height: 20px;
}
```